# How to send a business card to a mobile using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, java-me

Is there any way to send a business card to a mobile phone using C#?
I have an application in j2me which requires some set of data corresponding to some contacts so I want to send the business card of that contact via my server

Business Card is a type of special sms which contains the contact details of any person

Comment: I have an application in j2me which requires some set of data corresponding to some contacts so I want to send the business card of that contact via my server

Comment: As one send a business card from 1 mobile to another,what i want is to send it from my server

Comment: Business Card is a type of special sms which contains the contact details of any person

Comment: No, now it is clear what you are trying to do. Thanks for the explanation. You could now update your question to include all this useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get an [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) that will allow you to send SMS to mobile phones from your server.

Comment: do sms gateways provide a way to send business cards..
because i need the SMS to be received an a business card and get the contact stored in the contact list

Comment: @sourabh0612: it sounds like this "business card" is a very specific kind of SMS. Is it? If so, can you post a link to what exactly you mean? Maybe some kind of spec or something.

Comment: business card is also known as a vcard check this "http://www.ipipi.com/help/send-vcard-using-sms.htm" out